# How to automatically generate "good" names when decomposing existential hypothesis

Tags: coq

I have an existential hypothesis, such as:

```
H : exists (a : A) (b : B) (c : C), P a b c
```

which I want to decompose to:

```
a : A
b : B
c : C
H0 : P a b c
```

The tactic `decompose [ex] H; clear H` does exactly this, except that the names of the variables become `x`, `x0` and `x1` rather than `a`, `b`, `c`.  Is there any way to decompose this hypothesis, automatically generating "good" names (in the same way that `intros` would for a goal of `forall (a : A) (b : B) (c : C), P a b c`)?

Comment: Maybe this is doable using Ltac, but I don't know much about it. As a usual rule for my Coq files, I try to name most hypothesis by hand and never rely on the automatic naming of Coq. This makes scripts more robust. In your particular case, you could do `destruct H as [a b c HPabc]` for example.

Comment: While learning Coq, I have been told many times, by people with experience of the pain it can cause, not to rely on Coq's automatic naming of variables!  However, in this case, my proofs do not rely on these names, as subsequent tactics will determine the names through pattern matching.  But I'd still like the names to be "good" in order to make my life easier while manually inspecting the proof state.  Having dozens of variables all named `xN` can make things quite hard to read.

Comment: I see, then maybe some Coq/Ltac guru of the Coq-club mailing can help you :D good luck !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following tactic (a simplified, tidied-up and corrected version of Vinz's solution) achieves the desired result.

```
Ltac decompose_ex H :=
  repeat match type of H with
           | ex (fun x => _) =>
             let x := fresh x in
             destruct H as [x H]
         end.
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I think I managed (with some help :D) to do what you wanted:

```
Parameter A B C : Type.
Parameter P : A -> B -> C -> Prop.
Parameter Q : Prop.

(* This will try to match an hypothesis named h with 'exists u: T, P' 
   and return the name of 'u' *)
Ltac extract_name h :=
  match goal with
    | [h : ?A |- _ ] => 
      match A with
        | @ex ?T ?P => match P with
                          | fun u => _ => u
                   end
   end
end.

(* 'smart' destruct using the name we just computed *)
Ltac one_destruct h :=
   let a := extract_name h in
   destruct h as [a h].

Goal (exists (a:A) (b:B) (c:C), P a b c) -> Q.
intros H.
repeat (one_destruct H).
(* the goal is now
1 subgoals
a : A
b : B
c : C
H : P a b c
______________________________________(1/1)
Q
*)
```

I am not a skilled Ltac user, so this might not be completely perfect. Use at your own risks :)

Best,
V.

Comment: Aha!  I had tried to do something like this, but couldn't figure out the syntax to match an existential type.  (I think I was using `fun ?x => _` rather than `fun x => _`).

Comment: Your solution has a bug: if the name `a` is in use, then `one_destruct` will fail.  I've now fixed this bug in my answer, by using `let a := fresh a` to generate a fresh name (which will either be `a` or `aN` for some integer `N`).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to give the names manually.

```
Goal forall (t : Type) (p : t -> Prop) (q : Prop), (exists x : t, p x) -> q.
Proof. intros ? ? ? h1. elim h1. intros x h2. Abort.

Goal forall (t : Type) (p : t -> Prop) (q : Prop), (exists x : t, p x) -> q.
Proof. intros ? ? ? h1. inversion h1 as [x h2]. Abort.

Goal forall (t : Type) (p : t -> Prop) (q : Prop), (exists x : t, p x) -> q.
Proof. intros ? ? ? h1. destruct h1 as [x h2]. Abort.

Goal forall (t : Type) (p : t -> Prop) (q : Prop), (exists x : t, p x) -> q.
Proof. intros ? ? ? h1. induction h1 as [x h2]. Abort.

Goal forall (t : Type) (p : t -> Prop) (q : Prop), (exists x : t, p x) -> q.
Proof. intros ? ? ? [x h]. Abort.
```

Comment: True, but I'm looking for a solution that will generate these names automatically, since this code is to be used inside an Ltac definition that will be applied to hypotheses with different numbers of variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly linked but it's just to let you know that with the emacs compagny mode for coq you can achieve something similar for the `intros` (I'm not sure it works for `destruct` thought).

Do do so, just install compagny-coq (it's really powerverful, you should try it) using [this doc](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq). Then, when you add in your file some intros, just write `intros!` and then press `<Tab>`, and it will auto-complete. I'm not sure if the name are always the best ones, but at least it's deterministic, and won't break if you add a few lines before later.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to generate a name that's guaranteed not to clash with any existing name. You wouldn't know in advance what this name is, but you'd still be able to use it in tactics. I don't think it qualifies as nice though. You can use `idtac` to print it.

```
Goal forall (t : Type) (p : t -> Prop) (q : Prop), (forall x : t, p x -> q) -> (exists x : t, p x) -> q.
Proof.
intros ? ? ? h.
let h := fresh "h" in idtac h; intros h; case h.
let h := fresh "h" in idtac h; intros x h.
firstorder.
Qed.
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Generating "good" names is the whole point of the question.